# Full height sidebar with a background image

Tags: html, css

I need my sidebar to have a full height and also contain a background image.

[Here's the link to what I have so far.](http://redsky.incredifull.com/)
And here's my CSS:

```
/* Sidebar */
#sidebar {
background-color: #e7d9c9;
    background-image: url('/imgs/map.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 318px;
height: auto;
float: left;
padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#sidebar h1 {
border-bottom: thick;
border-bottom-width: 75%;
}

.sidetext {
    padding: 5px 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Helvetica Neue;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.sidelink {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
    width:300px;
}

.sidelink ul {
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.sidelink li {
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
}

.sidelink li a {
    display:block;
    font-family: Helvetica Neue;
    font-size:16px;
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color:#1e416f;
    padding:5px;
    border-left:10px solid #FFF;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.sidelink li a:hover {
    border-left:14px solid #1e416f;
    background-color:#e7d9c9;
    color: #1e416f;
}

h5 {
    font-family: Helvetica Neue: Light;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #517f9c;
}
```

It would also be **awesome** if someone could help me with the part that says "sidebar h1". What I'm trying to accomplish here is so that after every h1 I get a slight bottom-border 20px under the h1 and 20px of space after the bottom-border. It would also be in line with the rest of the text and links (20px left and 20px right) but I don't think it would be 75%. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Idk if your talking about asigning the height to the total height of another division or the body.

If you are talking about a division you need to asign a division relative to the body with another division inside asigned with the property of height 100%

if you want the height to be 100% of the body just do 100% after doing position absolute. that will work good.

Comment: Hi there, I'm actually talking about taking the tan of my sidebar and stretching it all the way to the bottom so that there's no white space underneath while also keeping the dark-er tan map image where it is. So literally just extending my sidebar's height to it's full capability.